# Bug: error in importing XLSX files when you're not an owner

Tags: google-drive-api

Steps to reproduce:

1. User A creates a Google Spreadsheet named "Tables".
2. User A shares "Tables" with User B.
3. Using the API, User B exports "Tables" into "Tables.xlsx", edits it, and then imports it back to "Tables".

The API always returns an error but "Tables" seems to be updated properly.

Comment: Please describe the error. Thanks.

Comment: It's 500 Internal Error.